# Oracle SQL query or script to find referential hierarchy of tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have several tables 'TABLE1', 'TABLE2', 'TABLE3' etc. in my Oracle Database having referential integrities between them.
Now I have a table 'TABLE_X' having 3 columns 'parent_table', 'child_table' and 'order_id'. This table 'TABLE_X' stores the hierarchy information of all the tables 'TABLE1', 'TABLE2', 'TABLE3' etc. The 'order_id' column corresponds to the level of table in hierarchy. For e.g. if 'TABLE5' and 'TABLE4' are children of 'TABLE3', and 'TABLE3' is child of both 'TABLE1' and 'TABLE2' then we will have the following 5 rows in 'TABLE_X':

```
     parent_table        child_table        order_id
     TABLE1              TABLE3             1
     TABLE2              TABLE3             1
     TABLE3              TABLE4             2
     TABLE3              TABLE5             2
     TABLE4              DUMMY              3
     TABLE5              DUMMY              3
```

I want to write a SQL or SQL script which gives me the whole output hierarchy in the following columnwise format :

```
     TABLE1    TABLE3   TABLE4  DUMMY
     TABLE2    TABLE3   TABLE4  DUMMY
     --------------------------------
     --------------------------------
```

Assume that the highest 'order_id' is 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT replace( sys_connect_by_path(parent_table,'/')||'/'||child_table, '/', ' ' )
FROM TABLE11
WHERE connect_by_isleaf = 1
START WITH ORDER_ID = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD_TABLE = PARENT_TABLE
;
```

**===== EDIT ===========**

You didn't mention in the question that you want to get also "intermediate combinations"

Just comment one line in the query to get these values:

```
SELECT replace( sys_connect_by_path(parent_table,'/')||'/'||child_table, '/', ' ' )
FROM TABLE11
WHERE connect_by_isleaf = 1
--START WITH ORDER_ID = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD_TABLE = PARENT_TABLE
;
```

This gives the following output:

```
 TABLE1 TABLE3 TABLE4 DUMMY
 TABLE1 TABLE3 TABLE5 DUMMY
 TABLE2 TABLE3 TABLE4 DUMMY
 TABLE2 TABLE3 TABLE5 DUMMY
 TABLE3 TABLE4 DUMMY
 TABLE3 TABLE5 DUMMY
 TABLE4 DUMMY
 TABLE5 DUMMY
```

Comment: Thanks kordirko... But it is not giving me correct result. It is not showing me the intermediate combinations like TABLE2-->TABLE3-->TABLE5

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example that shows how to get "intermediate combinations"

Answer (score 0):

Another way using WITH clause.

```
with tree ( root, parent, child,   path)
as 
(
 select parent_table,
        parent_table,
        child_table,
        parent_table || ' ' || child_table as  path
 from TABLE_X
 where order_id =1
union all
  select  t.root, 
          parent_table,
          child_table,
          path || ' ' || child_table
  from tree t
  left join Table_X X 
  on X.PARENT_TABLE = t.child
  where t.parent is not null
)
select Path from tree
where parent is null
```

It looks more complex than other example mentioned here but it may work almost without modification on other database types.

Comment: Thanks dcieslak. But it is not giving me the correct result. Its is showing DUMMY as direct child of some parent tables which have other children.

Comment: @Abhishek It's the answer for your question and it's correct. If you want something else then you need to describe more precisely. For your test data it returns 4 rows : `TABLE1    TABLE3   TABLE4  DUMMY , TABLE1    TABLE3   TABLE5  DUMMY, TABLE2    TABLE3   TABLE4  DUMMY, TABLE2   TABLE3   TABLE5  DUMMY`.  It's because TABLE3 is parent for TABLE4 and TABLE5.